# Struggling with row operations

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot

Below is the sample data. I am trying to do row operations and getting a bit confused. The desired result is below. First attempt at the the code is below as well and the resulting error. The purpose of this is to sum the 441 and 442 rows per period which gives a total retail sales for that time period and then chart that new 44 total and with the share (last row in result). However, the primary goal is to create the new sum row.

```
 library(dplyr) 


     area <- c("Clark","Clark","Douglas","Douglas","Clark","Clark","Douglas","Douglas","Statewide","Statewide")
    industry <-c(441,442,441,442,441,442,441,442,"000","000")
    employment <-c(100,50,101,65,102,52,103,67,1500,2200)
    period <- c("2016-1-31","2016-1-31","2016-1-31","2016-1-31","2016-2-28","2016-2-28","2016-2-28","2016-2-28","2016-1-31","2016-2-28")

   statewide <- data.frame(area,industry,employment,period)

   statewide <- statewide %>% (pivot_wider(names_from = industry, values_from = employment))

   Error in UseMethod("pivot_wider") : 
   no applicable method for 'pivot_wider' applied to an object of class "c('double', 
   'numeric')"


area     industry    employment     period
Clark        441        100          2016-1-31
Clark        442         50          2016-1-31
Douglas      441        101          2016-1-31
Dougals      442         65          2016-1-31
Statewide     44        316          2016-1-31
Statewide    000        1500         2016-1-31
Statewide    000       316/1500      2016-1-31
```

Before arriving at the end (above), I am thinking that the result after the pivot_wider would look like this. From there, I would sum the columns and then pivot_longer in order to produce the above result.

```
  clark441     clark442     douglas 441     douglas442     NewComputedColumn       period
   100            50            101             65            316      2016-1-31
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the way you've worded your goal. Would it be possible to show what result you expect?

Comment: @Jon Spring. The first four rows in the result show up in the statewide data frame before the pivot_wider. They represent industry employment in the county (Clark and Douglas). It is the fifth rows that is befuddling me. 316 is the sum of 100+50+101+65. Does that clarify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## New Answer

See below for how to fix the pivot error issue and why there is an error.

To achieve your desired output as explained in your comment, you do not want to pivot. You want to `group_by()` and `summarize()`.

```
library(dplyr)
  group_by(area, period) %>%
  summarize(employment = sum(employment))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   area [3]
  area      period    employment
  <chr>     <chr>          <dbl>
1 Clark     2016-1-31        150
2 Clark     2016-2-28        154
3 Douglas   2016-1-31        166
4 Douglas   2016-2-28        170
5 Statewide 2016-1-31       1500
6 Statewide 2016-2-28       2200
```

## Old Answer

The parentheses around your `pivot_wider()` call are unnecessary and are preventing `pivot_wider()` from working.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

statewide %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = industry, values_from = employment)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  area      period    `441` `442` `000`
  <chr>     <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Clark     2016-1-31   100    50    NA
2 Douglas   2016-1-31   101    65    NA
3 Clark     2016-2-28   102    52    NA
4 Douglas   2016-2-28   103    67    NA
5 Statewide 2016-1-31    NA    NA  1500
6 Statewide 2016-2-28    NA    NA  2200
```

Here is why the extra parentheses are trouble. The pipe operator `%>%` takes the output of one function and makes it the first argument of the next. That extra parentheses is taken to be the next function. Then, R is trying to evaluate the `pivot_wider()` call, and it does not have data to operate on. It interprets the arguments as back to the original vectors you defined in creating your data frame. Run the following code and get the same error:

```
pivot_wider(names_from = industry, values_from = employment)
```

Comment: I need a row that is the sum of 441 and 442 for each period. So for 2016-1-31.. it would be 100+50+101+65. 441 is sporting goods retail and 442 is grocery stores.. if that helps